# Como refazer este layout?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou estudando por uma apostila da caelum e temos que refazer este site [da Mirror Fashion](http://mirrorfashion.net). Mas fiz tudo como recomendado, cheguei até a copiar o código, mas não consigo fazer esta parte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento aparece todo quebrado como a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código html**

```
<div class="conteiner paineis">
<section class="painel novidades">
    <h2>Novidades</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/foto1-rosa.png">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/produtos/foto1-rosa.png" alt="Camisa feminia com flores rosas 129,00 reais.">
                <figcaption>129,00 reais.</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/miniatura9.png">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/produtos/miniatura9.png" alt="Conjunto de camisa quadriculada e short curto 60,00 reais.">
                <figcaption>60,00 reais.</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/miniatura6.png">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/produtos/miniatura6.png" alt="Vestido rosa 70,89">
                <figcaption>70,89 reais.</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/foto15-rosa.png">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/produtos/foto15-rosa.png" alt="Vestido para adolescente 126,78 reais">
                <figcaption>126,78 reais.</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/foto4-azul.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/produtos/foto4-azul.png">
                </figure>
                <figcaption>267 reais.</figcaption>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="img/produtos/miniatura3.png">
                <img src="img/produtos/miniatura3.png" alt="Casaco fino de cor verde 23,00 reais.">
                <figcaption>23,00 reais.</figcaption>
            </a></li>

        </li>
    </ol>
</section>
<section class="painel mais-vendidos">
    <h2>Mais Vendidos</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/foto5-azul.png">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/produtos/foto5-azul.png" alt="Ginástica 15,00 reais.">
                <figcaption>15,00 reais.</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/foto9-verde.png">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/produtos/foto9-verde.png" alt="Casaco quadriculado verde 67,80 reais.">
                <figcaption>67,80 reais.</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/foto11-azul.png">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/produtos/foto11-azul.png" alt="Short confortável para casa 9,50.">
                <figcaption>9,50 reais.</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/foto12-verde.png">
            <figure>
                <img src="img/produtos/foto12-verde.png" alt="Camisa de seda muito confortável por apenas 22,90 reais.">
                <figcaption>22,90 reais</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="img/produtos/miniatura10.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/produtos/miniatura10.png" alt="Conjunto adolescente de camisa e calça jeans por apenas 350 reais.">
                    <figcaption>350 reais.</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="img/produtos/foto4-rosa.png">
                <img src="img/produtos/foto4-rosa.png" alt="Casaco feminino para muito frio 456,90 reais.">
                <figcaption>456,90 reais.</figcaption>
            </a></li>

        </li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

**Código css**

```
.painel{
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 445px;
}
.novidades{
    float: left;
}
.mais-vendidos{
    float: right;

}
.painel li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 140px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.painel h2{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.painel a{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.novidades{
        background-color: #F5DCDC;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O uso do float é considerado ultrapassado atualmente. Recomendo o uso do flex-box quando o seu objetivo é alinhar items, pois ele é mais preciso que o float.

```
<style>
    .allContent {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        margin-left: 15%;
        width: 70%;

    }
    .left .right{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .left{
        background-color: lightcoral;
        width: 49%;
    }
    .right{
        background-color: lightblue;
        width: 49%;
    }
    figure img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
    }
    figure{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%;
        margin: 0 0;
        padding: 6px;
    }
    a{
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="allContent">
    <div class="left">
        <p> NOVIDADES </p>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="exemple.png">
                    <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
                </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <p> MAIS VENDIDOS </p>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="exemple.png">
                    <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
                </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="exemple.png">
                <figcaption> Exemplo 1 - R$ 25,00</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, a propriedade display: flex foi usado na div pai, além do uso do flex-flow: row nowrap, permitido, assim, colocar as div's filhas uma no lado da outra e de forma centralizada (margin-left: 15%).
  Para haver o alinhamento das imagens conforme o exemplo do site citado, ambas as div's filhas tem a propriedade display: flex, para possibilitar o uso do wrap (quebra de linha), e, para haver 3 imagens uma no lado da outra, a largura de cada figure foi configurado para 30%. Caso deseje responsividade, sugiro o uso de media queries ou do bootstrap.